# How to design db schema that preserves history without repetition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, architecture, database-schema

**Overview:** Business offer discounts. User can use discounts. Business offers multiple discounts but only available consecutively. Meaning, initially if you have not used any discount by a certain business... you only qualify for discount 1. Once you do use discount 1, you qualify for 2, then once you use 2 you qualify for 3.

**Functionalities needed:**

1. User can view all their past claimed discounts.
2. Use can view all available discounts to them, correctly find out which discount number (1|2|3) you qualify for each business.
3. Biz can view all deals they are offering
4. Discounts claimed do not change even if business changes their discount. nor does user history changes.
5. Biz should be able to get list of all claimed and not expired discounts.

My first solution was simple create 4 tables:

- Biz
- User
- Discount
- UserDiscount

Biz creates discounts, user acquire them and that gets saved in UserDiscount.
Biz has one to many relation with Discount. Discount has one to many with UserDiscount.

Problem is if biz updates their discount or delete it, it completely alters user's history, and redeemded discounts even though they hadn't expired.

Second was to create whole copy in UserDiscount. But that looks like a lot of duplication.

Third is to every time business updates, or deletes their discount simply create new record in Discount. But now i've to add a flag to every discount if whether if this is the active one, and before there were like 3 records, now there could be 100s, depending how many times business updates their stuff.

Comment: In a data warehouse this is achieved with SCD2. Every configuration of the same item has a start and end date. If there are many configurations, the current one has a flag indicating that. If you need to store multiple states then there's no way around storing multiple records. Your third option makes the most sense to me. Records will balloon out, but that's what databases are for

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem with altering the history and minimize duplication you should not be editing the records in the discounts table but rather add new records when needed. You may add the flag for if a discount is active, but you'd be better with using effective date/expiration date. one optimization you can make is to allow editing discounts that have not been used yet to minimize unused lines in the table.